# filling two d array from 6 source files efficiently

Tags: c, performance

First Ill give the details:

I have scanned in 6 source files which correspond to 6 different regions. The data is information about earthquakes which I have stored in the following structures:

```
  typedef struct {
int year;
int month;
int day;
char time[9];
  } datetime_t;

 typedef struct {
datetime_t datetime;
double latitude;
double longitude;
double magnitude;
double depth;
char location[LOCATION];
  } data_t;
```

I then created 6 arrays, one for each region:

```
    data_t Alaska[MAX_INFO];
data_t Central[MAX_INFO];
data_t Inter[MAX_INFO];
data_t East[MAX_INFO];
data_t West[MAX_INFO];
data_t Canada[MAX_INFO];
```

Now my goal is display a 31x6 two d array which displays the number of earthquakes per day per region. I know I can do on like this for 31 days, for 6 regions, but there must be a more efficient way:

```
     for (i=0;i<A;i++)
    {
        if (Alaska[i].datetime.day == 1)
        {
            day_array[0][0] = i;
        }
        else if (Alaska[i].datetime.day == 2)
        {
            day_array[1][0] = i - day_array[0][0];
        }
        else if (Alaska[i].datetime.day == 3)
        {
            day_array[2][0] = i - day_array[1][0] - day_array[0][0];
        }
    }
```

Ive thought of something along the lines:

```
  for(j=0;j<REGIONS;j++)   /*particularly these two parts to fill the array*/ 
    {
        for(i=0;i<DAYS;i++) /*but I end up with same problem*/
        {
            for(k=0;k<A;k++)
            {
                if(Alaska[k].datetime.day == 1)
                {
                    day_array[i][j] = k;
                }
                else if(Alaska[k].datetime.day == 1)
                {
                    day_array[i][j] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }   /*I KNOW THIS DOESNT WORK AS IS */
```

I know technically I could just do the first thing I have for the 186 total days with a for loop for each region, but I feel as though there is a much more efficient way to do this and I just don't seem to see it...I don't need anyone to tell me how to, but rather a push in the right direction would be great if anyone can help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems your objective is to avoid writing separate code for each array.  In that case, you have several alternatives, among them

- Use a two-dimensional array instead of your several current 1-D arrays, in which the extra dimension represents your different regions; then use nested loops
- Create an array of array pointers (`data_t *regions[] = {Alaska, Central, Inter, East, West, Canada};`) and use it as if it were a 2D array.
- Create a function that takes a `data_t *` and analyzes it however you want.  Pass each of your per-region objects to it.

Comment: I tried using ( data_t *regions[6] = {Alaska,Central,Inter,East,West,Canada};) right below (data_t Canada[MAX_INFO];) which according to some other posts looks like its in the right spot, but I get an error: initializer element is not computable at load time in c. I tried adding the data_t *regions to the data_t structure and that didn't help either, any thoughts?

Comment: If the individual region arrays are not global variables then you cannot (in C) use an initializer of the form I gave.  You can still use this approach, however, by explicitly initializing the `regions` array in code: `regions[0] = Alaska; regions[1] = Central;` etc..